# "Webpages" or "Web Pages"?

Tags: word-choice, orthography, spacing, variants

Sometimes I found it written as "WebPages" and sometimes it is "Web Pages" ..
I'm confused should it be written as one word or two words ?!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is largely a matter of style; adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, observe the guidance of whichever [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) suits your taste and audience. For more general coverage of compounds, see *[When should compound words be written as one word, with hyphens, or with spaces?](/questions/889)*

Comment: This new-fangled technobabble evolves quickly.  When electronic mail was new, it was written “e-mail” or “E-mail”; now it’s commonly “email”.  Probably in ten years, nobody will write “web page” as two separate words. … … … … … … … But, really?  You’ve seen “WebPages”, with a capital “P” in the middle of a compound word?  That’s surprising.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question of fairly broad interest that different dictionaries answer differently, meaning that "research" conducted at any single "general-reference" resource is likely to yield an incomplete or misleading answer. For those reasons, I think this question should be reopened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an Ngram chart of "web page" (blue line) versus "web pages" (red line) versus "webpage" (green line) versus "webpages" (yellow line) for the period 1980–2019:

[image]

As you can see, the two-word versions of these terms were strongly favored from roughly 1995 through about 2009 in the published documents included in the searchable Google Books database, but then they began to decline in frequency while the single-word forms continued to become more common. According to the data from Google Books, the two-word forms were still more common than their one-word counterparts as of 2019, but I expect that the trends favoring the one-word forms will continue and that *webpage* and *webpages* will be more common by 2030—and perhaps much sooner.

One reason for this change is that many English set phrases (such as "child care" and "check list") eventually compress from two words to one as they become commonplace in writing. Another reason is that trendsetting sources may favor the closed-up form owing to their early familiarity with the term.

In the case of "web page"/"webpage," I recall that the shift from the two-word spelling to the one-word spelling occurred in 2012 or 2013 at the two computer magazines where I was working at the time. A shift of that sort can have outsize influence because the term occurs more often in such specialized forums than in the outside world and because dictionaries often accord more weight to style choices that arise within a particular field or discipline than to style choices made by nonspecialists.

Merriam-Webster Online lists the term under the spelling [*web page*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/web%20page) (with *Web page* as an alternative spelling), although MW's most recent *Collegiate Dictionary*, the *Eleventh Collegiate* (2003) has no entry for the term at all. In contrast, the American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language Online lists [*webpage*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=webpage) as the primary spelling (and *Web page* as an acceptable variant). In print, *AHDEL* has included an entry for *webpage* since the fourth edition (2000).

Comment: Good answer, Sven – but it ignores the adjectival usage. Both *web pages* and *webpages* are likely to be used only as nouns, but *webpage* is readily used in adjectival form: *webpage layout*, *a webpage feel*. While *web page* could also be used as a modifier, I'd be much more likely to use the single-word form in such a situation, or I'd hyphenate it as a compound modifier: *the web-page layout*. Your Ngram would benefit from a further categorisation of those two PoS for each of *web page* and *webpage*, to give greater clarity to what's going on with the **noun** form.

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica: Your points are valid. Unfortunately, Ngram is not designed to track hyphenated forms (for example, it replaces "web-page" with "web - page" in its search results, and then, predictably, finds very few matches for "web - page"—none of which it links to beneath the Ngram graph). Ngram is quite useful for comparing unpunctuated open and closed forms of the same term, but it is very nearly worthless for assessing the frequency of occurrence of hyphenated or apostrophed words.

Comment: Yes, I understand the hyphenation issue, but that's not what I was suggesting. I recommended using Ngram's facility for complex search parameters to differentiate between webpage [noun] and webpage [adjective], as the OP is only asking about the noun form, whereas your Ngram result for *webpage* potentially includes adjectival usages and thereby skews the data to make it look like the single-word noun is more prevalent than it really is.

Comment: PS I realise that in *webpage layout*, *a webpage feel* etc, *webpage* functions as a noun adjunct rather than an adjective. But the issue is whether ***Ngrams*** identifies any adjectival usage. Perhaps there are modern books with sentences like *Your essay looks too webpage*. If Ngrams regards this usage as an adjective, then the results you've provided are an overestimation of the single word's prevalence as a noun. I hope my reasoning makes sense! :-)

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica: Undoubtedly the results for singular _webpage_ benefit from some instances of _webpage_ as an adjective-like modifier in addition to instances of _webpage_ as a standalone noun versus _web page_ almost entirely as a standalone noun phrase. But searches for the phrases "webpage design" and "webpage layout" barely register on the same-scale Ngram graph, suggesting that the proportion of instances of _webpage_ as a modifier is not very large in comparison with the proportion of instances of _webpage_ as a standalone noun in Google Books search results. ...

Comment: [Here's an Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=web+page%2Cweb+pages%2Cwebpage%2Cwebpages%2C+webpage+design%2C+webpage+layout&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cweb%20page%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cweb%20pages%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwebpage%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwebpages%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwebpage%20design%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwebpage%20layout%3B%2Cc0) for "webpage design" vs. "webpage layout" vs. undifferentiated "webpage," "web page, "web pages," and "webpages." The line plots for "webpages" and "web pages" probably contain very few adjective forms.

Comment: [Here's the Ngram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=webpage_ADJ%2Cwebpage_NOUN&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwebpage_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwebpage_NOUN%3B%2Cc0) for adjective vs noun usage for "webpage". So Ngram *does* identify some adjectival usage, albeit not enough to change your original results very much. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In English, *one* word **can** be written with a space in between, e.g., "mineral water". In some languages, it can be written as a single word, e.g., "mineraalwater" (Dutch). That maybe confuses us.

I'd say it's "webpage", because "website" is also correctly spelled without a space.

Comment: A belated Hello, 260. I feel the answer needs clarification. (a) Compound nouns exist (as do compound verbs etc) in English. While 'ink' and 'well' are not compound nouns, 'inkwell', whose etymology is obvious, is. (b) Compound nouns are found in various orthographic forms. There are solid forms, hyphenated forms, and open forms, the latter considered still to be a 'single word' by some authorities. Which form or forms a given compound exists in can be checked in dictionaries. With inkwell / ink-well / ink well, all three spelling variations are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found from several sources on the Web, what you see on your screen in your Web browser is a Web page. It is considered the same thing as a book page. If you are referring to more than one Web page on a site, then the term is Web pages. Example: I found four Web pages on x site which provided a lot of information about bolt and nut sizes in both SAE and Metric sizes.
The question now becomes should the word after Web be capitalized? After all, if a Web page is a book page, why shouldn't it be a web page? And here is the BIG question: Why do we capitalize web. i.e., Web? If you search for Web page, you will many results that include "web page" or "web pages." Same thing for the program you are using to view this document, it can be a Web browser or a web browser. I guess it just continues so show the the English language is the most complicated and hardest language to use.

Comment: Please consider formatting your answer in a more readable fashion. Also, it would help lend credibility to your answer if you cited sources that support your claims - authoritative sources other than _from what I have found_.

Comment: @Skeptic_50, if you take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read about [good answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center, you'll better understand what was meant about reformatting. There's no need to be condescending or critical.

Answer (score 0):

Upon cursory literature review, here's my May 2023 1-year status update on this question:

Wikipedia leads off with [web page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_page) (or webpage), so it appears to be "web page" barely(?), but's getting close. From these comments, it sounds like it's only a matter of (not very much) time before webpage surges ahead, never to look back.

Oh wait - this just in from the APA Style Guidelines (which we use in my classes): [Preferred Spellings](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/spelling-hyphenation/preferred-spellings). They say webpage but then home page? I had those reversed personally. I would go with AP Style if I had access to their Stylebook; a [summary page of AP Style](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/subject_specific_writing/journalism_and_journalistic_writing/ap_style.html) at Purdue's Online Writing Lab includes some technology terms (at the bottom) that better align with my choices than the APA styles do, but it doesn't include webpage.

In related news, website wins hands-down over web site, and it's been ahead for years, but I only switched fairly recently (ok boomer). I use these terms quite a bit at work now, so I've done some research over the past year or so. And more today, it turns out.

I don't know why the plurals would be any different.

Also, I stopped capitalizing web and internet long before I gave in to website over web site. It just made more sense after the newness was gone.